# What does the R glm-error "Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values" mean? I have supplied starting values

Tags: r, glm

I am trying to do a binomial regression model for some of the variables in my dataset.

The model:

```
glm.test <- glm(
  anydiagnosis ~ gender + age + socioeco_status + dsdm_category + 
    family_history + mental_before_hiv + relations + sexual_life + 
    stigma_discrimination, 
  family = binomial(link=log), 
  data=finaldata
)
```

When I run the model, I got the error message: "Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values".

I have been told that glm has some converge problems in R, and therefore, the solution might be to first apply a logistic regression model, predict the outcome of this, and defining the outcome as starting value for the binomial model:

Logistic regression model:

```
glmfit <- glm(
  anydiagnosis ~ gender + age + socioeco_status + dsdm_category + 
    family_history + mental_before_hiv + relations + sexual_life + 
    stigma_discrimination,
  family = binomial(link=logit), 
  data=finaldata
)
```

Predicting the start values:

```
mustart <- predict(glmfit, type="response")
```

Testing if the binomial model works:

```
glm.test2 <- glm(
  anydiagnosis ~ gender + age + socioeco_status + dsdm_category + 
    family_history + mental_before_hiv + relations + sexual_life + 
    stigma_discrimination,
  family = binomial(link=log), 
  data=finaldata, 
  mustart = mustart
)
```

However, I still get the same error code even though I have tried to supply starting values.

I am a quite inexperienced R-user, so there is definitely a chance that I am missing something :)

Comment: [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/485690/glm-with-log-link-in-binomial-family) is a post from CrossValidated that might help.  Among other useful resources, the accepted answer points to the [`logbin`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/logbin/logbin.pdf) package in R to estimate these models.

Comment: "I have tried to supply starting values".  The error message suggests that you did not succeed.  However, we can't provide you with concrete advice until your example is *reproducible*. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Specifically, we need to have (a sample of) your data and - ideally - view of your `mustart` object.  [Are you sure you need fitted values for your data rather than estimates of the coefficients of your model?]